# NSFormatter and NSdate issue. Getting nsdate object null

Tags: iphone, ios

I am getting date null and I dont know why, Can someone please help

Input date: @"June 14, 2012 - 00:00:00 UTC"

Expected output: @"June 14, 2012"

```
                NSString *rawDate = @"June 14, 2012 - 00:00:00 UTC";
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy - HH:mm:ss"];
                NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:rawDate];

                NSLog(@"Check the string date: %@", date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
NSString *rawDate = @"June 14, 2012 - 00:00:00 UTC";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy - HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:rawDate];

NSLog(@"Check the string date: %@", date);
```

You need to add a format identifier for the timezone portion of the input string.